# Error loading module when using lua

Tags: lua, torch

I'm new to lua and recently learning DL with Torch.
I have installed torch just following instructions: http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html#_ and added some packages using `luarocks install`. Then I wrote a test file:

```
require 'torch'
require 'nn'

--[[do something]]
```

when running with `lua test.lua` (Ubuntu 14.04), it errs as followed:

> error loading module 'libpaths' from file
>   '/home/user1/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/libpaths.so':
>     /home/user1/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/libpaths.so: undefined symbol:
>   luaL_register

It seems something wrong with path settings or so. However, when I run test with command `th`, it works fine.
I searched and examined these answers: [Error loading module (Lua)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700342/error-loading-module-lua)
[Torch7 Lua, error loading module 'libpaths' (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036340/torch7-lua-error-loading-module-libpaths-linux)
not fully answered my question though.
So I wonder where exactly the error comes from, and how to fix it. Even though I can use torch with `th`.

ADD:
I find that the reason maybe API `luaL_register` is not supported in ver 5.2 which is what I am using, while `th` calls a lua shell in ver 5.1? So does this mean I can only use `th` to run my files?

Comment: Before installing torch, did you have Lua already installed on your machine? What do you get if you do: `which lua` and `which luajit`?

Comment: Yes, I installed lua before torch. And it shows /usr/bin/lua and /home/user1/torch/install/bin/luajit, so can I run lua with  specific version appointed?

Comment: You clearly need to use either `luajit` or `th` and not your system-wide `lua` install. Otherwise it conflicts with Torch install (rocks are not installed at the right place, plus your Lua version is > 5.1 hence the troubles with parts of Torch code that have been compiled for lower `LUA_VERSION_NUM`, etc).

Comment: It means that you buld libpaths with include files from different Lua version than you run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely using your system Lua (probably version 5.2), but Torch requires LuaJIT it comes with. Run your script as `luajit test.lua` (it's probably in `/home/user1/torch/install/bin/luajit`).